# How to convert from momentum to energy distribution? (relativistic electrons)

Tags: special-relativity, energy, particle-physics, momentum, plasma-physics

I am using a gyro-kinetic simulation tool [2103.16457](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.16457) which solves the 3D Fokker-Planck equation for the electron population in tokamak plasmas and evolves plasma parameters self-consistently. In many cases, there can be relativistic electrons (runaway electrons) in these populations. I use the code in 1D space and 2D momentum space. The code calculates the $f$ momentum [distribution](https://ft.nephy.chalmers.se/dream/frontend/api/Settings/eqsys/distribution.html) of the runaway electrons and at each timestep outputs the values in the cells on a 3D grid. The 3 dimensions of this grid are the following:

1. Minor radius in the plasma: $r$
2. Total momentum of electrons: $p$
3. Pitch: $\xi$ which is the cosine of the angle between the momentum vector of a specific electron and the local magnetic field line

First, the code can do a so-called angle averaging in pitch, leaving only a 2D grid behind. I need the (particle) density moment of the distribution and the code calculates it and I am left with the quantities
$$\frac{dn}{dpdr}$$

My question is how to "move" from the momentum grid to the energy grid and get
$$\frac{dn}{dEdr}$$

The momentum is stored in units of $m_ec$ (suppose $p=\gamma m_ev=bm_ec$, and I know $b$) so initially I was just multiplying the values with 511 keV. However, the momentum grid in my specific use case starts from 2.5$m_ec$, so it would be better to do the correct conversion. If I understand correctly I would need to convert from constant $dp$ cell widths to varying $\alpha dE$ cell widths (where $\alpha$ is just an unknown). Given that I know where the momentum cell edges of the grid are, I can convert them to (kinetic) energy cell edges. Using $b$, with some work I can get the $E$ energy at a specific momentum:
$$\frac{p}{m_e}=\gamma v=bc$$
$$b=\frac{v}{c}\gamma=\beta\gamma=\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$$
$$1-\beta^2=\frac{\beta^2}{b^2}$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{b^2}+1\right)\beta^2=1\implies\beta^2=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{b^2}+1}=\frac{b^2}{b^2+1}$$
$$E=(\gamma-1)m_ec^2\implies E=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{b^2+1}}}-1\right)\cdot 511\mathrm{keV}$$

but I was told that doing this in itself is not enough since the Jacobian during the conversion of the $dn/(dpdr)$ quantity will result in an additional term.

How do I get this Jacobian in the first place and what is the resulting final conversion I have to do? I would prefer an energy grid in electronvolts but I can convert from Joules as well.

[Further physical documentation of the code](https://github.com/chalmersplasmatheory/DREAM/blob/master/doc/notes/theory.tex) (in .tex file)

Comment: I just edited my answer below to add further clarification on some potential Jacobian factors you also might need (assuming your code is doing the $\xi$ integration right).

Comment: @JosephRobertJepson Thank you. I will look into how the code does the integration in $\xi$ and try to implement the conversion.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope my answer helps.

Comment: Just noticed another slight error in my answer (in the physical space part of the Jacobian), so I just fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$p_\parallel$ has a hidden $\xi$ in it which is not integrated over initially when you integrate over pitch angle.  This is the factor you are not taking into account. If you did the coordinate transformation first, and then integrated over pitch angle you would get the correct distribution.  I get that $\bar{f}(E_{\text{tot}},r)=\int_{-1}^1\text{d}\xi\ f(\cfrac{\xi}{c}(E_{\text{tot}}^2-(m_ec^2)^2)^{1/2},\xi,r) $, where $p_{\parallel}=\cfrac{\xi}{c}(E_{\text{tot}}^2-(m_ec^2)^2)^{1/2}$, and the original $f$ is $f=f(p_\parallel,\xi,r)$.  Here $E_{\text{tot}}$ is total energy (hence the rest energy subtraction).

Edit: However, I don't know how your code is doing that averaging.  Assuming it is doing the averaging correct (transforming to $p$ or $E$ from $p_{\parallel}$ first, before doing the $\xi$ integral), then I think you are also missing some extra Jacobian factors in your transformation.

I can illustrate assuming that we have a circular cross section torus.  To integrate the distribution function over both physical and velocity space, I first assume we use physical space coordinates $(r,\theta,\phi)$ ($r$ a flux surface label, $\theta$ angular position on a flux surface, $\phi$ toroidal angle), and velocity space coordinates $(p,\xi,\gamma)$ (with $\gamma$ the gyro-angle).  Then, assuming the distribution function is $f=f(r,p,\xi)$ (independent of the angular parameters), I get:

\begin{align}
n&=\int f\ \text{d}^3x\text{d}^3v=\int f\ r\text{d}\theta(R_0+r\cos(\theta))\text{d}\phi\text{d}r p^2\text{d}\xi\text{d}p\text{d}\gamma\nonumber\\&=R_0(2\pi)^3\int f\ r\text{d}r p^2\text{d}\xi\text{d}p\ ,
\end{align}

where $R_0$ is the magnetic axis.  Now we do the $\xi$ integral to get $\tilde{f}(r,p)\equiv \int f\ \text{d}\xi$.  This then leads to us concluding that:

\begin{align}
R_0(2\pi)^3\tilde{f}(r,p)\ r p^2=\cfrac{dn}{dpdr}\ .
\end{align}

We now just need to figure out how the integral transforms when changing from $(r,p)$ to $(r,E)$.  $E$ here will represent relativistic kinetic energy, (not total energy), to agree with your definition above.  (I modified the $E$ above to read $E_{\text{tot}}$ to avoid confusion).  The Jacobian of the transformation is:

\begin{align}
\left|\text{det}\left(\cfrac{\partial (p,r)}{\partial(E,r)}\right)\right|=\left|\text{det}\begin{pmatrix}\cfrac{E+m_ec^2}{c^2p(E)} & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right|=\cfrac{E+m_ec^2}{c^2p(E)}\ ,
\end{align}

where $p(E)=(1/c)((E+m_ec^2)^2-(m_ec^2)^2)^{1/2}$.  Using this Jacobian, we have:

\begin{align}
n&=R_0(2\pi)^3\int \tilde{f}(r,p)\ r\text{d}r p^2\text{d}p\nonumber\\&=R_0(2\pi)^3\int \tilde{f}(r,p(E))\ r\text{d}r p(E)\cfrac{E+m_ec^2}{c^2}\text{d}E\ .
\end{align}

This then shows that

\begin{align}
\cfrac{dn}{dEdr}=R_0(2\pi)^3\tilde{f}(r,p(E))\ rp(E)\cfrac{E+m_ec^2}{c^2}\ .
\end{align}

Finally this implies that

\begin{align}
\cfrac{dn}{dEdr}(r,E)=\cfrac{dn}{dpdr}(r,p(E))\cfrac{E+m_ec^2}{c^2p(E)}\ ,
\end{align}

so simply transforming the grid doesn't get you all the way there.  You need to also multiply by that extra Jacobian factor of $\cfrac{E+m_ec^2}{c^2p(E)}$.

Comment: I finally had time to look into this and I realized that the code stores the distribution on a grid with the total momentum $p$ instead of just $p_{||}$ so I will update my question. I believe this doesn't have a huge impact on the answer.

Comment: Also, could you clarify where $r$, $(R_0+r\cos(\theta))$ and $p^2$ come from in the integral $\int f\ r\text{d}\theta(R_0+r\cos(\theta))\text{d}\phi\text{d}r p^2\text{d}\xi\text{d}p\text{d}\gamma$?

Comment: I suppose $(R_0+r\cos(\theta))$ is due to the circular cross-section torus?